# Ruby on rails parent nav active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, menu

I'm trying to set an active class on a navigation item, if i'm on a child page.

Here's what I have:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def active_class(link_path)
      current_page?(link_path) ? "active" : ""
     end

    def active_parent_class(link_path)
        current_page?(controller: link_path)
    end
end
```

The active_class helper works, so I tried to modify it for parent class. I'm using:

```
active_parent_class('sections')
```

In my menu. My controller is called 'Sections'. So basically anytime i'm in any page from the sections controller, I want to add a class to a menu item.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the `request.path` with the input `path`. If part of the `path` is also included in the `request.path` it is also active:

```
  def parent_nav_is_active?(path)
    rp=request.path
    if rp == path
      true
    elsif rp.include? path #child page check
      true
    end
  end
```